# VBA Formula Setting in a for Loop - Syntax Issue

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hi Trying to get some help to see why this is not working in a Macro that I have setup. The area where the debugger causes an issue is at the 2nd Selection.Formula area.

```
Sub PrintAllonges()
'
' PrintAllonges Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Y
'

Dim pdfName As String, FullName As String, Path As String, lRow As Long


Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Path = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").specialfolders("Desktop")

' Create Desktop Folder if not exists

If oFSO.FolderExists(Path & "\Allonges") Then
Else
    MkDir Path & "\Allonges"
End If
    
'Turn off Screen Update

Sheets("MissingAllonges").Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox (lRow)
Sheets("AllongeTemplate").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


For i = 2 To lRow

    Range("G6").Select
    Selection.Formula = "=MissingAllonges!I" & i
    Range("E11").Select
    Selection.Formula = _
        "=TEXT(MONTH(MissingAllonges!D" & i & "),""mmmm"")&"" ""&DAY(MissingAllonges!D" & i & ")&"", ""&YEAR(MissingAllonges!D" & i & ")"""
         

pdfName = Sheets("AllongeTemplate").Range("H7").Value & " - " & Sheets("AllongeTemplate").Range("G6").Value & " Allonge"
FullName = Path & "\Allonges\" & pdfName & ".pdf"


ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FullName, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next i


Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

I put this in and got to work for other formulas where I am updating the loop but I can't get this to work and getting an error on syntax.

Comment: Your formula looks quite off. Why are you using `MONTH` and `DAY` and `YEAR`? Probably should be something like `=TEXT(MissingAllonges!D1, "mmm d yyyy")` Also you don't need a loop to write this formula.

Comment: The loop is due to me continuing to change the contents of a cell with a different reference for each i in the loop.

Comment: Have you tried using a simpler formula yet? Side note, you're probably going to get unintended results with `TEXT(MONTH(...),"mmm")`. Try for example `=TEXT(MONTH("12/12/21"),"mmm")`.

Comment: Whenever I see `Range.Select: Selection.Stuff` I cant help but comment that you can simplify this into `Range.Stuff` which not only makes it easier to read, but also speeds it up nearly 10x, makes it less jittery on the screen during execution and improves the reliability of the code.

Comment: @BigBen - Thanks for the Help just really starting to try and do more in VBA now appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra quotation marks at the end of the formula.

The corrected formula would be:

```vb
.Formula = "=TEXT(MONTH(MissingAllonges!D" & i & "),""mmmm"")&"" ""&DAY(MissingAllonges!D" & i & ")&"", ""&YEAR(MissingAllonges!D" & i & ")"
```

But I agree with @BigBen that the formula could be simplified, ie:

```vb
.Formula = "=TEXT(MissingAllonges!D" & i & ", ""mmmm d, yyyy"")"
```